# How do I consolidate copy and rename commands into one using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Currently I am using PS to copy files from a network location based on a CSV file, then I am renaming them using a variation of the same data.  This requires that I run two separate commands.

How do I consolidate these commands into one?

Copy:

```
import-csv C:\TEST\test.csv | foreach {copy-item -path $_.npath -destination 'C:\TEST\'}
```

Paste:

```
import-csv C:\TEST\test.csv | foreach {rename-item -path $_.lpath -newname $_.newalias}
```

Notice that the -path trigger in each case refers to a separate variable header, npath vs. lpath which correspond to the network file location, and then a local file location which have been manually entered.

On the same note, how could I concatenate this variable to constant data.  If I have a variable **fn** which represents the file name and another **path**, could I theoretically do:

```
foreach {rename-item -path 'C:\TEST\' + $_.fn
```

Or:

```
foreach {rename-item -path $_.path + $_.fn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append the two commands

```
import-csv C:\TEST\test.csv | foreach {copy-item -path $_.npath -destination 'C:\TEST\';rename-item -path $_.lpath -newname $_.newalias  }
```

for your second question there are lots of ways to append string

```
C:(...)WindowsPowerShell>$data = "bob"

C:(...)WindowsPowerShell>echo "this is a $data"

C:(...)WindowsPowerShell>$concat = "hi" + " george"

C:(...)WindowsPowerShell>$concat
hi george

C:(...)WindowsPowerShell>[string]::Format("{0} {1}","string 1","string 2")
string 1 string 2
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to consolidate the two commands to access only a single variable, i.e. is there a command that allows you to copy a file and then rename it?  This would be similar to: foreach {copy-item -path $_.path -destination 'C:\TEST\' -newname $_.newalias}?  The problem here is that there is no -newname trigger for copy-item.  In reference to appending a string, can you concatenate two variables by simply using a plus sign, i.e. $_.path + $_.fn would work?

Comment: Just use string concatenation in the destination parameter of copy item  copy-item -path $_.npath -destination "C:\TEST\$_newalias"

Comment: The "C:\TEST\" is not always constant.  At times I will need to append $_.fn to $_.path to get the complete file path.  I've tried $_.path + $_.fn, but this results in an error.

Comment: add ( ) to for evaluation ($_.path + $_.fn)